# How to solve divisible triangular problem (ProjectEuler) efficiently in Kotlin?

Tags: algorithm, kotlin, numbers, factors

I was solving problems on the the [ProjectEuler](https://projecteuler.net/), And I am stuck on the [12th problem](https://projecteuler.net/problem=12), the following code takes too longer not even done in five minutes and my CPU got warm.

Essentially what I am doing is generate a sequence of triangular numbers by adding successive natural numbers like:

- 1 -> 1 (i.e. 1)
- 2 -> 3 (i.e. 1+2)
- 3 -> 6 (i.e. 1+2+3)

And so on, then finding the first triangular number which has more than 500 factors (i.e. 501 factors).

```kotlin
fun main() {
    val numbers = generateTriangularNumbers()
    val result = numbers.first {
        val count = factorOf(it).count()
        //        println(count) // just to see the count
        count > 500
    }
    println(result)
}

// Finds factor of input [x]
private fun factorOf(x: Long): Sequence<Long> = sequence {
    var current = 1L
    while (current <= x) {
        if (x % current == 0L) yield(current++) else current++
    }
}

// generates triangular numbers, like 1, 3, 6, 10. By adding numbers like 1+2+3+...n.
private fun generateTriangularNumbers(from: Long = 1): Sequence<Long> = sequence {
    val mapper: (Long) -> Long = { (1..it).sum() }
    var current = from
    while (true) yield(mapper(current++))
}
```

The count (number of factors of triangular numbers) is hardly getting over 200, Is there a way to efficiently solve this problem, maybe within a minute?

Comment: Quick google found somebody else's attempt: https://github.com/Package/Euler-Kotlin/blob/master/src/com/euler/Euler12.kt

Comment: @AdamMillerchip Tried that, its been 1 minute of again processor getting hot, still looks similar to my solution somehow.

Comment: @AdamMillerchip you can also see the description of main function stating that it will take 10 minutes on a decent system. Mine is i3-5th gen lol. I wanna see if there's any algorithm that computes it any faster.

Comment: The `n`th triangular number is `n * (n+1) / 2`, which avoids a lot of addition.  Also, factors come in pairs, one less than the square root matching one greater than the square root.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Project Euler is about math. Programming comes second. You need to do some homework.

- Prove that triangular numbers are in form of `n*(n+1)/2`. Trivial.
- Prove that `n` and `n+1` are coprime. Trivial.
- Prove, or at least convince yourself, that `d(n)` is [multiplicative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplicative_function).

Combine this knowledge to come up with an efficient algorithm. You wouldn't need to actually compute the triangular numbers, and you would need to factorize the number much smaller; memoization would also avoid quite a few factorizations.

Comment: Thanks! These points are really helpful, Hopefully I will do it :)